# WPF binding not applied - why does it happen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wanted to update a stringformat of my binding via a datatrigger. So I thought of just doing this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Name}" Margin="3">
                  <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                      <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=., StringFormat='Start {0}'}" />
                      <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo.IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=., StringFormat='Stop {0}'}" />
                      </DataTrigger>
                      </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                  </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
```

now this just shows the value of Foo.Name and not with the string format applied('start'/'stop' string).

I've modified the code, to get it working. This is the working code:

```
        <TextBlock Margin="3">
          <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
              <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Foo.Name, StringFormat='Start {0}'}" />
              <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo.IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Foo.Name, StringFormat='Stop {0}'}" />
                </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
          </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
```

Now i'm looking for the reason why the first piece of code doesn't work and why the second piece of code works.
I've seen similar behavior in DataTemplates where I could not set or alter a property value via a Setter in a DataTrigger because the property was already set directly via the property on the object itself. Only when I removed the property from the object itself and set it as a style it worked.

Or is this just a limitation in WPF?

Comment: it is [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx). Local value (`Text="{Binding Foo.Name}"`) is more important than style setter value

Comment: so the datatrigger "stop" in the first example is also not applied because of this precedence?

Comment: style setters are #8, style triggers are #6, local values beat them being #3

Comment: If you set a property via an attribute on the XML element, *nothing* you do to it in a Style will have any effect. This is so a particular control can override parts of its style, at your discretion. The easy fix is to set the property's initial value only in a Style Setter -- you had that right in the first example; you could have dispensed with the attribute. The other problem was that `Path=.` was wrong; the DataContext was still the parent of `Foo`, so the Path in all the Text bindings should still have been `Foo.Name`.

Comment: ok thanks for clearing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a limitation, it's documented. Dependency properties have a value precedence. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx